# Inserting columns to the right of changing last column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet like this:

[image]

Each month, I have to insert the same 9 columns to the right of existing columns. Can anybody help me with inserting rows to the right of last column using VBA/macro. The last column ("i" in this sheet) would change very month with the addition of 9 columns. Also along with inserting columns, I also want to copy text in the inserted columns.

I would appreciate your time and help regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Dim c as range

set c = activesheet.cells(1,columns.count).End(xlToLeft).offset(0,1)

with c.Resize(1,9)
   .value = Array("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", _
                   "Tab4", "Tab5", "Tab6", _
                   "Tab7", "Tab8", "Tab9")
   .font.bold = true
end with
```